# Better approach to serialize data that contains multiple related Models using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

## Background

I am new to Django and DRF and I am currently writing a view that handles a `GET` request. The view will return a JSON that contains data associated with 5 related models. Here is a visualization of my database [image]. And this is what I expect to get

```json
[
    {
        "word": "hello",
        "entries": [
            {
                "tag": null,
                "link": "",
                "value": "TEST"
            },
            {
                "tag": null,
                "link": "",
                "value": "STUFF"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "word": "Hello",
        "entries": []
    }
]
```

## Problem

My current approach is to use Django query to construct a self defined object and then define a DRF serializer to serialize it. The code looks like this

```py
# Inner Object
class DetailEntry():
    def __init__(self, tag, link, value):
        self.tag = tag
        self.link = link
        self.value = value
# Outer Object
class ReviewEntry():
    def __init__(self, word, entries):
        self.word = word
        self.entries = entries
    
class GetReview(APIView):
    
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # get current user
        currentUser = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)

        records = Record.objects.filter(user_id=currentUser)

        reviewEntries = []
        for record in records:
            word = record.word_id
            quotes = Quote.objects.filter(record_id=record)
            
            detailEntries = []
            for quote in quotes:
                tag = quote.tagAssignment_id
                link = quote.link
                value = quote.value
                detailEntries.append(DetailEntry(tag, link, value))

            reviewEntries.append(ReviewEntry(word, detailEntries))
        s = ReviewSerializer(reviewEntries, many=True)
        
        return Response(s.data)
```

```py
class QuoteSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    tag = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    link = serializers.URLField()
    value = serializers.CharField(max_length=300)


class ReviewSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    word = serializers.CharField(max_length=150)
    entries = QuoteSerializer(many=True)
```

**The code works as expected, but the code looks stupid that it contains a nested loop and two additional classes. Thus, I wonder if there's a better approach to solving this.**

Also, after some research I noticed that DRF official websites documented [serializer relation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/). But it seems that I have to implement a serializer for each model and construct the response data totally based on serialization without using Django Query.

It's highly appreciated for telling which way is more industry-standard like or even better approaches.

Comment: you have to serializer all models data and its a better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    def get(self, request, format=None):
    # get current user
    #currentUser = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)

    records = Record.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Also, use to_represantation method in your serializers.